# Why does this Kotlin code not print anything?

Tags: kotlin

This code is supposed to print the `=` symbol. But, when I run the code, it shows nothing … and my code editor says:

> Variable 'age' is never used
> Variable 'layer' is never used.

I don't understand what is happening here (note: I am a total beginner).

```
fun main() {
    val age = 24
    val layers = 5
    // printCakeCandles(age)
    fun printCakeTop(age: Int) {
        repeat(age + 2) {
            print("=")
        }
        println()
    }
    // printCakeBottom(age, layers)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. You are never calling the function `printCakeTop`, ie the only function that would print something
2. the `age` you define with `val age = 24` (line 2) is a different variable than the `age` parameter in `function printCakeTop(age: int)` (line 5 and 6).
3. As all function calls, that would use your `age` or `layer` variables are commented out (`//`) , they are marked as unused.

So the following would print something, and also use the `age` variable

```
fun main() {
    val age = 24
    val layers = 5
    // printCakeCandles(age)
    fun printCakeTop(age: Int) {
        repeat(age + 2) {
            print("=")
        }
        println()
    }

    printCakeTop(age);
    // printCakeBottom(age, layers)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution. Problem solved. 

Answer (score 2):

you need to call printCakeTop function to print